# iText table margin left

Tags: java, itext

How is it possible to set a left margin or right margin to a table (not to content in single row)? I want something like `setSpacingAfter()` and `setSpacingBefore()` but horizontally. There is `setIndentationRight()` for Paragraph but I can not find something like that for a table.

Comment: Put the whole table inside an outer table with a single cell and set padding left/right on that outer cell?

Comment: Make two columns extra in that table First & last with the size you want & remove all the borders. That's it.

Answer (score 2):

You can indent a table if you put it into an indentated paragraph.

```
table = new PdfPTable(2);

// Makes the table to get the 100 percent of space that is available horizontally
table.setWidthPercentage(100);

// Creates a paragraph indentated by the left by 20 units.
p = new Paragraph();

// You insert the table into the indentated paragraph.
p.add(table);

p.setIndentationLeft(20);

// And finally, this will show a table indentated to the left by 20 units.      
document.add(p);
```